# Tensorflow Object Detection API dictionary error

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am using the [object_detection_tutorial.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb) to run an inference.

After I run the inference, I got this error on the **output_dict**:

```
  # Run inference
  output_dict = model(input_tensor)

  # All outputs are batches tensors.
  # Convert to numpy arrays, and take index [0] to remove the batch dimension.
  # We're only interested in the first num_detections.
  num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections'))
  output_dict = {key:value[0, :num_detections].numpy() 
                 for key,value in output_dict.items()}
  output_dict['num_detections'] = num_detections
```

Error log:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "detect.py", line 140, in
>   
>       show_inference(detection_model, image_path)   File "detect.py", line 109, in show_inference
>       output_dict = run_inference_for_single_image(model, image_np)   File "detect.py", line 94, in run_inference_for_single_image
>       **num_detections = int(output_dict.pop('num_detections')) TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not**
>   'Tensor'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved upgrading to tensorflow 2.0